# How to use the API Sesame with Tomcat server into a Java dynamic web project?

Tags: java, tomcat, sesame

I developed an Java application who request in SPARQL on Sesame repositories.
I use currently a Tomcat server what I run on console (with ./startup.sh).
I must now include my application into a web page and I choose J2EE.
But I have a problem : I can't run a Sesame connection and use JSP files, servlets,...together.
I have this error :

Etat HTTP 404 : The requested resource is not available

How to "join" us ? Is it a conflict because of the "8080" port ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html

Comment: I find nothing about connection to Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information about how you have configured your Tomcat to allow a meaningful diagnosis.

But I can say with certainty that it is *possible* to run Sesame repositories and JSPs on the same Tomcat service ... if you configure them correctly.  Indeed it is possible that you are *already* doing this, but you are using the wrong URL to access the resource.

> How to "join" us ?

I suggest that you start by looking at the Tomcat documentation on how to configure the server, and how to build a basic webapp.

> Is it a conflict because of the "8080" port ?

That is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't touch really at the Tomcat configuration. I downloaded the version 7.0.54 on the Tomcat website and on the webapps directory I added the .WAR of Sesame : openrdf-sesame.war and openrdf-workbench.war (it's this way that my application runned when I was a simple Java project)